# Raw pointer type for interior mutable struct

Tags: pointers, rust, ffi, erlang-nif

I’m doing some Rust FFI work for the Erlang NIF API, and I have these:

```
ErlNifEnv *enif_alloc_env();
void enif_free_env(ErlNifEnv* env);
```

This ErlNifEnv pointer gets passed to a variety of other functions but the user will never deref the pointer.  Also, this pointer is not threadsafe (use amongst multiple threads would require a mutex).  The naive Rust representation of this type would be..

```
struct ErlNifEnv;
*mut ErlNifEnv;
```

But, I think I can treat this type as having “interior mutability” which would lead to…

```
struct ErlNifEnv;
*const ErlNifEnv;
```

Should I be treating this pointer as const even though the underlying C code sees it as non-const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think that you should treat them as you treat references in Rust itself. When a function requires `&mut` reference, it is very likely that it will actually change the value, and if it requires `&`, then it is natural to expect that the value won't be changed (of course, disregarding inner mutability).

C does not have a distinction between inherited and inner mutability, and so you can choose what to use `*mut` or `*const` solely based on how C functions work with this value. In fact, in properly written C API this distinction will be present in form of `const` qualifiers. Consequently, if there are any functions which want to mutate the value, go with `*mut`. If there are no such functions (e.g. this is an immutable structure which is created only once) go with `*const`. This is, of course, applies to the type you want to store in your wrapper - in FFI function signatures you should always mirror C API signatures.